# htmlHelper.RouteLink not generating the URL I want

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, routes

Hi I am trying to take advantage of the [great article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207602/Creating-a-Bilingual-ASP-NET-MVC3-Application-Part) to make localization available in my mvc3 site. Without areas is working perfectly but introducing areas in my site i have come to this problem:

```
htmlHelper.RouteLink(linkText, globalisedRouteData)
```

where globalisedRouteData:

```
4 Keys: Culture, Area, Controller, Action
4 values: en, soluciones, home, index
```

is not generating the expected (for me): host/en/soluciones/home/Index
but: /soluciones/Home?culture=en

What is breaking me is this ?culture=en. Why is not being embeded the /en/ as it is contained in globalisedRouteData?

In my RegisterRoutes, I placed:

```
        const string defautlRouteUrl = "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}";
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        RouteValueDictionary defaultRouteValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(new {area="soluciones_de_salud",   controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
        routes.Add("DefaultGlobalised",  new GlobalisedRoute(defautlRouteUrl, defaultRouteValueDictionary));
```

Thanks¡¡

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change the use of 'id' into 'culture'

ie

```
const string defautlRouteUrl = "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{culture}";

RouteValueDictionary defaultRouteValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(new {area="soluciones_de_salud",   controller = "Home", action = "Index", culture = UrlParameter.Optional })
```

When the route binding occurs the parameter name must match the route parameter otherwise you end up with

```
?ParamName=Value      (?culture=en)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `id` in `culture`

If the culture is mandatory in your url remove also `id = UrlParameter.Optional`

```
const string defautlRouteUrl = "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{culture}";
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
RouteValueDictionary defaultRouteValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(new {area="soluciones_de_salud",   controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
routes.Add("DefaultGlobalised",  new GlobalisedRoute(defautlRouteUrl, defaultRouteValueDictionary));
```

If culture is not mandatory and you would set a default value

```
const string defautlRouteUrl = "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{culture}";
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
RouteValueDictionary defaultRouteValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(new {area="soluciones_de_salud",   controller = "Home", action = "Index", culture = "en" });
routes.Add("DefaultGlobalised",  new GlobalisedRoute(defautlRouteUrl, defaultRouteValueDictionary));
```